# DELETE requests directly from the command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following this tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#fnref-9_4 and after the code in Listing 9.44 author says that in that specific moment any user can be deleted with a direct DELETE request from the command line, of course I believe that it's true but I don't know how to check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any sufficiently sophisticated attacker could simply issue DELETE requests directly from the command line to delete any user on the site.

Here's an example of a command line DELETE call using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)

```
$ curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

`http://localhost:3000/` is the path to your app, `1` is the ID of the record to delete.

With cURL you can simulate the same requests you will perform using your browser. You can use any other HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL from the command line to make HTTP requests, including DELETE requests.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/persons/person/1
```

** Adapted from [this blog post](http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/)